# SQL query result in single row

Tags: sql

[image]

I need result in single row with extra column `vcTest1`.

Expected output:

[image]

Comment: How many VcTest values can be there for a group, Is it always two or more than two

Comment: When asking a question, please supply table structures, sample data, expected output, what you've tried and why/how that does work. Also, text is much more preferable to images as people can't copy and paste code/data from an image. Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Just group by all the fields but the `VcTest` :

```
select week, lab_no, area, key_map, max(VcTest) VcTest, min(VcTest) VcTest1
from your_table
group by week, lab_no, area, key_map
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear why you want two non distinct row to one row

`TestResult` and `vcTEST` is different in two rows Otherwise Distinct will work for you. If you really want to output one row you need to replace `testresult` and `vcTest` with same value then apply `DISTINCT`

Comment: its not about distinct , combine two rows as one , check second pic, there is extra coloums VCtest1

Comment: Why RAMP Test in output not Vector Test ?